# High frequency Ultrasonic transducer for finer mist making

Tags: piezo, transducer

I am looking to make Mist/Fog from water using ultrasonic transducer mist maker. A typical mist making products in the market are using 1.7 MHz ultrasonic transducer to make 5 Micron size Mist/Fog. How ever, I am looking for 1 Micron size or below Mist makers. Do you think if I increase the frequency of the piezo ultrasonic transducer from 1.7 MHz to 2.4 MHz, 3.0 MHz or higher ones (5 MHz to 10 MHz) and may that lead to finer (1 Micron or below) mist/fog I am looking for?

Is there a corelation between the frequency of the piezo ultrasonic transducer and the density of the mist produced?

I would really appreciate someone input and advice on this. thanks

Jay

Comment: I'm not sure anyone here is prepared to develop a quantitative answer based on first principles. I'm not sure anyone can. So this sounds like an experimentalist's research project to me.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. This question is off-topic as it has several questions, with some question more related to physics. Density is a physical property, etc. Recommend migration to Physics.SE.

Answer (score 1):

From what research I found (99 page thesis) it appeared in 1986 that the most efficient transducer conductance to water was around 1.5MHz on page 71 .

Therefore in answer to your question, I think not.

http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/17/083/17083027.pdf